# Remove text color and background color in Tiptap/Prosemirror on paste

Tags: javascript, tiptap, prose-mirror

How can I remove the color and background color from pasted text in tiptap/prosemirror, in a clean way? I have a specific palette of colors that are allowed for the text in the editor, and I don't want people pasting from other places to be able to overwrite that.

I could intercept the paste, parse the string and remove style attributes but I'm thinking there must be a cleaner way to do this.

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I'm also strunggling with it...

Comment: In the end I made a (relatively) hacky solution by intercepting the transformPastedText and transformPastedHTML and removing the styles that I don't want there. Not ideal, but couldn't find another solution